# Where can i find objective c xcode sample codes for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sample

i am a new programer and i would like to find some sample projects to learn from. Do you know any website that might help me?

Sample programs such us:
Uitable views
Uiscroll view
Plist storing data
Do to project
Note taking projects
Etc

Answer (score 3):

The documentation links to useful sample projects at the top of most references.

[image]

Comment: The "Companion Guide" sections, when available, are also fantastic as they have short code samples with thorough explanations.

Comment: where did u find this ? do i need to pay 99usd/yr to apple for this?

Comment: No. It's just the documentation. Did you download Xcode already? It's in there. It's also [online](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?filter=passkit).

Answer (score 0):

You can also login into ios dev center (developer.apple.com/iphone/) and there is section "Sample Code" with all examples.
You can search by something specific for you or view by Topic/Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this book, it helped me allot and there is everything you need to know about programming for the iPhone: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Teach-Yourself-Application-Development-Yourself/dp/067233576X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1354751889&sr=8-2

However if you goal is to program games I would use some of these packages: http://www.cartoonsmart.com/flash_mobile_index.php5

Another option is youtube there are tons of videos teaching you everything you need to know. For example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mB-o3gtbHpg&list=PL8B9E3607FA1EEFCE

Best advice is definitely the first one. It helped me the most :)